# Unable to delete array element using 'read -n 1' character as array index

Tags: arrays, bash, element, unset

I'm trying to dynamically delete elements from an array in bash based on a script argument of the form '123' where each single digit number in the argument is assumed to be an index of the array which should be removed.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Doesn't delete an element.
ARRAY=(a b c)
while getopts ":a:" opt; do # run e.g. 'thisscript.h -a 0'
    case $opt in
        a)
            echo -n $OPTARG |\
                while read -n 1 c; do
                    unset ARRAY[$c]
                done
                ;;
    esac
done
echo ${ARRAY[@]}
# Deletes an element successfully.
ARRAY=(a b c)
unset ARRAY[0]
echo ${ARRAY[@]}
# Deletes an element successfully.
ARRAY=(a b c)
n=0
unset ARRAY[$n]
echo ${ARRAY[@]}
```

Write this to e.g. tmp.sh file, chmod +x tmp.sh to make executable, then run 'tmp.sh -a 0'.

Why doesn't the first array element deletion method work, and how can I make it work within the 'read -n 1' context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the PIPED while-read loop which runs as a subshell. Therefore, the `unset` occurs in a subshell and disappears when the subshell exits. That's why there is no effect on the array variable.

This problem is described in [Section 20.2. Redirecting Code Blocks](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/redircb.html) of the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide.

Here is one workaround, using process substitution instead of a pipe.

```
while read -n 1 c; do
    unset ARRAY[$c]
done < <(echo -n $OPTARG)
```

Comment: How interesting - thanks very much for the explanation dogbane. I'd like to understand the usage of double '<' in your example, but can't find the string '< <' in the page you linked to. Is there a name for the construct that I can Google to find out more?

Comment: `<(...)` syntax is called process substitution.